# Magic Trackpad 2 cannot be paired again after pairing with another device

Tags: macbook-pro, magic-trackpad

The problem is the following, I have two MacBooks, (MacBook A and MacBook B) and a trackpad.

When I connect (via Bluetooth) the trackpad with MacBook A, everything is fine.
Later I turn off that MacBook A and turn on MacBook B.
I connect (via Bluetooth) the trackpad to MacBook B, everything fine.

Much later, I turn off MacBook B and turn on MacBook A, the trackpad does not connect, although I see it in the list of Bluetooth devices I can not connect, I have to choose "forget device" and pair again; The same happens every time I switch MacBook between A and B.

Any idea?

Comment: The short answer is the Trackpad is designed to be paired with one device only.  Once paired, it doesn’t switch easily.  See the dupe for different solutions to this.